# Which Shaiva / Shaivite sect was started by or joined by Vishnu & Brahma?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, brahma, shaivism, agamas

According to [Skanda Purana 1.3b.16](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370669.html) this happened after Shiva commanded his 2 creations - Vishnu & Brahma - to worship him as per the Agamas:-

> Viṣṇu and Brahmā wore matted hair and applied sacred ash over their bodies.... **They themselves became preceptors, and performed the rites of initiation etc. to the people there belonging to all the castes** in accordance with their merits.... Thus Brahmā and Viṣṇu propitiated Aruṇa-Śaṅkara for sixteen thousand years and attained Śivajñāna.

So Vishnu & Brahma became GURUS of some kind. Was this any existing Shaiva sect? If so, which one / what was its name? If it was a new sect started by them - what was the name of that Shaivite sect? Please give sources!